# How to create an HTML link from specific elements on a page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

So I'm trying to make a website, and I custom coded an additional button on the product pages of the website. Now that button appears on all product pages, and in the backend, I can only specify one link. I want that to be different based on what product I'm on.

Is there any way to fetch the Product ID of the item, or fetch the link, and then in the backend, I can make it dynamic so the link would be based on what product page I'm on?

For example on this page: http://thefutureofjewelry.com/product/capital-a-charm/

I put the custom button (the 360 button), but it only links to one file that I specify. Can I make it so that the link is dynamic in the sense it is based on the product code? So the link would be different on every page.

Would that be possible? Or is there a better way around it maybe?

Comment: Is the product code you're interested in the same as the product ID, which here is 3925?

Comment: Yup! Different for each item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I was able to get it done! In case anyone's interested or might need help in the future!

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_extra_button_on_product_page', 30 );

function my_extra_button_on_product_page() {
   global $product;
   $prodid = esc_attr($product->get_id());
   $produrl = 'http://thefutureofjewelry.com/wp-content/uploads/360videos/'.$prodid.'/';
   echo '<a data-fancybox="gallery" href="'.$produrl.'"><img border="0" alt="360 View" src="http://thefutureofjewelry.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/360_Icon.png" width="50" height="50"></a>';
}
```